# Invariance of the square of the four vector and a hyperbola

Tags: special-relativity, spacetime, vectors

The invariance of the square of the relativistic four vector is given by

$\begin{equation}c^2t^2-x^2-y^2-z^2=d^2\end{equation}$.

What I am unsure of is if this then relates to the hyperbola shown in the space-time diagram below, labelled E.

[image]

Could someone clear this up?

Comment: Please do not post formulae as screenshots, but use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/143136) instead.  I realize you cannot do this for the graph but at least the initial part should be reasonably straightforward.

Comment: @ZeroTheHero Edited it - just seemed easier at the time considering how neat the image was

Comment: The hyperbola is the locus of events whose interval ($d$ in your math) from the origin is the same.   It is the hyperbola of your equation.